# How to convert octal to string without change the value?

Tags: python, python-2.7

How to convert 00024 to '00024' with python?

If I run 00024 in python shell, it print 20 as result. I want to convert 00024 to string, with the result is '00024'. Any suggestions?

Comment: No, `00024` is *not* printing 24. It prints 20, because it is an octal number.

Comment: Ah sorry, I mistyped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to represent *integers* with leading zeros, [`format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format) the number to a string explicitly:

```
format(integer, '05d')
```

Whenever you output values, `print` implicitly converts it to a string with `str()`, with `format()` you get to control how that conversion takes place explicitly.

When you echo a number in the interactive interpreter, `repr()` is used instead, but for integers the output is exactly the same as when you use `str()`.

Demo:

```
>>> format(24, '05d')
'00024'
```

When you enter `00024` as an integer literal, Python 2 parses that as an octal number, in Python 3 that's a syntax error.

If you want to interpret such a number in the Python 2 shell *as if it was a string*, you cannot do what you want, not with an *arbitrary number of leading zeros*. You can, at best, re-format the resulting integer as octal, again with leading zeros. That'll produce a string again, but you have to hardcode the number of leading zeros:

```
>>> number = 00024
>>> format(number, '05o')
'00024'
```

Note that this'll also fail as soon as you have a number that *doesn't* have a leading zero; you could auto-detect such values if they are greater than 4095 (07777 octal):

```
strnumber = format(number, '5d' if number > 0o07777 else '05o')
```

and *any* number with leading zero and the digits 8 or 9 simply fails with a syntax error:

```
>>> 09876
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    09876
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
```

Your better bet is to just enter such numbers *as strings* instead.

Comment: I have data with this digit 00024 and I want to convert to string. But not change the value.